# JavaMail - getMessageCount changes after opening imap folder?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm writing a program that connects to gmail and checks the number of messages in the inbox. If I call `getMessageCount()` on the unopened `Folder`, it returns 554, but after opening it, it returns 541. Why the difference?

By the way, I'm ultimately trying to check for deleted messages (that have not been expunged) and recover them if possible.

**Edit:** some example code:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(System.getProperties());
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.googlemail.com", 993, email, password);
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
System.out.println(inbox.getMessageCount());
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
System.out.println(inbox.getMessageCount());
```

**Edit:** protocol trace:

(In the meantime I got some more emails so the numbers are different from above)

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.googlemail.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK Gimap ready for requests from <ip> vt17mb17567619iec
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 XYZZY SASL-IR AUTH=XOAUTH AUTH=XOAUTH2 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
A0 OK Thats all she wrote! vt17mb17567619iec
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=imap.googlemail.com, user=<email>, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 OK <email> authenticated (Success)
A2 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT IDLE NAMESPACE QUOTA ID XLIST CHILDREN X-GM-EXT-1 UIDPLUS COMPRESS=DEFLATE ENABLE MOVE CONDSTORE ESEARCH UTF8=ACCEPT
A2 OK Success
A3 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST (\HasChildren) "/" "INBOX"
A3 OK Success
A4 STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES RECENT UNSEEN UIDNEXT UIDVALIDITY)
* STATUS "INBOX" (MESSAGES 585 RECENT 0 UIDNEXT 3389 UIDVALIDITY 2 UNSEEN 0)
A4 OK Success
585
DEBUG IMAPS: connection available -- size: 1
A5 EXAMINE INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Draft \Deleted \Seen $Phishing $Forwarded NonJunk $NotPhishing Junk)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Flags permitted.
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 2] UIDs valid.
* 548 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDNEXT 3389] Predicted next UID.
* OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 687472]
A5 OK [READ-ONLY] INBOX selected. (Success)
548
```

Comment: Does Javamail allow you to take a protocol trace?

Comment: [It does](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).  You'll probably have to ask Google why the server returns different numbers in these different cases.

Comment: cannot reproduce with imaps protocol (do you used gimap?)

Comment: @salyh no, in fact I haven't heard of gimap

Comment: can you please do session.setDebug(true); and post the protocol trace?

Comment: @salyh done (a bit late :p)

Comment: Looks like a bug. One of them, likely STATUS is lying.